# How to list and kill threads/processes in Perl without using external command(s)?

Tags: multithreading, perl, shell, process, kill

I need to **kill** some processes and threads *(if exist)* in **Perl** application, but I don't want to use external command(s) such as `ps`, `grep`, `awk`, `cut`, `uniq` or `kill`.

My current code is:

```
      my $appName = $0;
      $appName =~ s/^.*\/([^\/]*)$/$1/;
      $_ = qx(kill -9 `ps -eLao pid,command | grep '$appName\[ 0-9\]*\$' |
              grep -v grep | awk '\$1 != $$' | cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq` 2>&1);
```

I am using VPS, so my memory is limited. The code above sometimes returns `undef`, as system cannot allocate memory for call of external command(s). I am looking for alternative solution without using external command(s).

Comment: I don't have any experience using it, but [`Proc::ProcessTable`](http://search.cpan.org/~durist/Proc-ProcessTable-0.39/ProcessTable.pm) might be of use.

Comment: Using a pipeline of `grep` and `cut` with `awk` is a red-flag even when used in a shell let alone Perl. `awk` can match and snip.  Since you are using Perl, you don't need any of these external utilities to perform the parsing.

Comment: I need to list all processes and **threads** as well, as `ps` option `-L` is for threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use internal kill commands like [`kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) and the `/proc` fs or some modules like `Win32::Process::List` or anything in the `Proc::` namespace.

Comment: I need to list all processes and **threads** as well, as `ps` option `-L` is for threads.

Comment: For processes I am going to use model `Proc::ProcessTable` and internal Perl command `kill` as suggested. But so far there is no solutions for all threads, such an alternative of `ps -eLaf`.